# Deriving instance Typeable with context

Tags: haskell, deriving

I am writing function set wor working with HTTP requests and need to create a set of Exceptions for handling failures. Here it is

```
data HStream ty => ErrorResponse ty = ErrorResponse (Response ty)
data HStream ty => HttpException ty = WrongURIException String | ConnException ConnError | RequestException (ErrorResponse ty)
instance HStream ty => Exception (HttpException ty)
```

where `WrongURIException` corresponds to malformed uri, `ConnException` to errors in TCP stack and RequestException to handle responses with non-2xx response codes.
Before declaring `instance Exception` on line 3 I should derive Typeable but I'm lost in types. How should I it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might I suggest *not* doing that. Datatype contexts are bad in pretty much every way possible. There's a reason that they've been deprecated. If you really, really, want them, use GADTs.

If you don't use contexts, this is trivial

```
 {-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
 import Data.Typeable
 import Data.Data


 data ErrorResponse ty = ErrorResponse (Response ty)
                       deriving(Data, Typeable, Show)
 data HttpResponse ty = WrongURIException String 
                      | ConnException ConnError
                      | RequestException (ErrorResponse ty)
                       deriving(Data, Typeable, Show)
 instance (Typeable ty, Show ty) => Exception (HttpException ty)
```

In particular as of GHC 7.8 you can't make your own instances for `Typeable` and `Data`, so deriving is the correct way.

Comment: Understood. But how should attach non-2xx responses to exceptions to leave compiler decide which type of response body should be?